# What does this shell script do? What are headingcopy and linecopy? variables?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

can somebody pls help me understand what is happening here in lines started with headingcopy, linecopy, and sed, don't fully understand what these headingcopy or linecopy mean as I don't recognize these commands and, if they are variables, where are they used?...

```
GetReportParams|grep -iv conn|grep -v "^$"|while read DB_SCHEMA REP_IDX ORG_SHORT_NAME SQL_SCRIPT OUTPUT_FILE_NAME REPORT_NAME REPORT_TYPE OUT_FILE_EXT ORG_NAME MAIN_EMAIL BCC_EMAIL REPORT_GROUP PARAMETERS
do
  echo ======================================================================================
  export DATE=`date +%Y%m%d -d "1 day ago"`
  export OUTPUT_FILE_NAME="${OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}_$DATE.${OUT_FILE_EXT}"
  export OUTDIR=$OUTDIR_main/${ORG_SHORT_NAME}/${YEAR_MONTH}
  export SCPDIR=/$ORG_NAME/data_extracts/
  TMP_FILE_NAME="TMP_RUN_REPORT.txt" 
  echo Running report for -- $PARAMETERS
  # Remove text qualifier character
  PARAMETERSSEARCH=`echo $PARAMETERS | tr -d \'`
  HeadingCopy=`head -1 $OUTDIR_main/$MAIN_FILE_NAME | tee -a ${OUTDIR_main}/${TMP_FILE_NAME} `
  LineCopy=`grep ^"$PARAMETERSSEARCH" $OUTDIR_main/$MAIN_FILE_NAME | tee -a ${OUTDIR_main}/${TMP_FILE_NAME} ` 
  sed 's/[ \t]*$//' ${OUTDIR_main}/${TMP_FILE_NAME} > ${OUTDIR}/${OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}
  sed -i 's/[^,]*,//' ${OUTDIR}/${OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}
  #cat ${OUTDIR}/${OUTPUT_FILE_NAME}
  rm ${OUTDIR_main}/${TMP_FILE_NAME}

  rsync -a ${OUTDIR}/${OUTPUT_FILE_NAME} oracle@grnwebreports2:$SCPDIR
done
```

Thanks!
Leo

Comment: `man head` and `man tee` is a good start; read those and then get back here with specific questions if you still don't understand.

Comment: Referring people to user manuals is useful, I'm wondering why these kind of comments are not in the header of every technical forum in the net, it could help a lot by avoiding almost any question (if not all) as everything is in the manuals :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HeadingCopy=`head -1 $OUTDIR_main/$MAIN_FILE_NAME | tee -a ${OUTDIR_main}/${TMP_FILE_NAME} `
```

copies the first line from the file $OUTDIR_main/$MAIN_FILE_NAME  to the variable HeadingCopy and also redirects(appends) the output to a file ${OUTDIR_main}/${TMP_FILE_NAME}

```
 LineCopy=`grep ^"$PARAMETERSSEARCH" $OUTDIR_main/$MAIN_FILE_NAME | tee -a ${OUTDIR_main}/${TMP_FILE_NAME} `
```

copies the line which start with the string that is present in the variable PARAMETERSSEARCH and 
also redirects(appends) the output to a file ${OUTDIR_main}/${TMP_FILE_NAME}

second sed  will replacs every line  the data in the file from the first character till it encounters a ","

Comment: Got the sed lines now. The first one removes trailing spaces, the second one removes anything up to the first comma (effectively removing the first field of a csv file) Thanks!